# Detect whether two dates expressed in a text are the same

Tags: library, nlp, formatter

I'm looking for a program or library that can detect whether two dates expressed in a text are the same.

For example:

- "Dec. 2012" = "December 2012" = "2012-12"
- "Monday, December 6" = "December 6"
- "December 6, 2020" != "2020-12-07"

---

- Operating system: preference for Linux or Windows.
- License: any
- Price: any
- Language of the text: preference for English.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TEXirj

Comment: The first example is not precise date, its month. The second the equation depend of year. For me looks like XY problem

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks I'm also interested when the date it doesn't specify the exact date or the exact year

Comment: Franck, this looks like good example for AI, the options are too much for sample interpretation.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks I'm open to an AI-based solution